error: changing the current version under key "cocoapods"
Image
enter image description here
When typing the command eas build -p ios gives me that error, please if you can help me, I am working from a regular laptop, it is not a Mac
When typing the command eas build -p ios gives me that error, please if you can help me, I am working from a regular laptop, it is not a Mac
When typing the command eas build -p ios gives me that error, please if you can help me, I am working from a regular laptop, it is not a Mac.
